# Go to next textfield when hit Return

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios5

I wrote a `textFieldDone:` method that's suppose to move the cursor to the next textfield when the Return button is tapped.

```
- (IBAction)textFieldDone:(id)sender {
     [nextTextField becomeFirstResponder];
     NSLog(@"in : textFieldDone");
}
```

I have connected the first textfield's "Did End On Exit" event to the File's Owner and chose the `textFieldDone:` method.
I also assigned the File's Owner as the textfield's delegate (because I need the view to scroll up/down accordingly so the keyboard won't hide the textfields).

When I run the app on the simulator and tap the return button the first textfield resign first responder and in the log I see that the program didn't go through the `textFieldDone:` method, but it did go through the `textFieldDidEndEditing:` method.

I used that method before and had no problem.

Is it because the File's Owner is the textfield's delegate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if ([textField isEqual:txt1]) 
    {
        [txt2 becomeFirstResponder];
    }
    return true;    
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to write on

```
- (BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField*) textField
```

to go to next text field.

Sample code:

```
-(BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField*) textField 
{
    if (textField == txt1)
    {
        [txt1 resignFirstResponder];
        [txt2 becomeFirstResponder];
    }
    if (textField == txt2)
    {
        [txt2 resignFirstResponder];
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Don't forget to add delegate `UITextFieldDelegate` to your UITextfield.

Answer (score 1):

the above answers are correct, but to make this more general you should use the tag option

```
UITextField *txt1;
txt1.tag=1;
UITextField *txt2;
txt2.tag=2;
UITextField *txt3;
txt3.tag=3;
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if ([[textField superview] viewWithTag:textField.tag+1])
        {
        [[[textField superview] viewWithTag:textField.tag+1] becomeFirstResponder];
        }
    else{  [textField resignFirstResponder];
    }
    return true;
}
```

note: don't use `textField` with tag 0. because all `subViews` have tag=0 by default.